# Where can I find good collaboration tool?

Tags: project-management

I'm working on a project where I'm using mindmeister.com as a tool when brainstorming new ideas.

Now I need a tool where I can define roles and what responsibilities they have, and link this to a person / persons. It would also be nice if I could add tasks with a due date for each person.

Are there any open source websites which has this?

### **PS.**

The tool must be light weight, and not strictly for programmers only.
Main usage would be **before** development stage.

**Update**
Ok, after some more thinking, it looks like I need some kind of project template tool.

I have this project. In order to be succesfull, I need to cover task A, B and C.
Task A has sub tasks like a1, a2 and a3.

Now this is still just descriptions of things I must think of / answer, in order to have a successful project.

When those Qs have ben answered, I can start delegating tasks to project members which again can break down the tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) - it is a lightweight wiki and issue tracking tool.

Answer (score 1):

"Redmine" has many features to collaborate with others in projects.

Also, using a Redmine client app, such as "mintRedmine", will help your team get the best outcome out of the features in Redmine fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

[GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/) is good for breaking down project responsibilities to persons and defining timelines.

Comment: I've used GANT charts before, and in some way it pretty similar to what I need. But the tasks do not have a start / end timeline. Not at this stage anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Collabtive](http://collabtive.o-dyn.de/) is the best one I've used. I think it should cover the functionality you're asking for. They also offer hosting for reasonable prices.

[DotProject](http://www.dotproject.net/) is also an alternative, but without the good looks...

Answer (score 0):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) is great.